# Oracle ADF h:commandButton f:ajax not working

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, oracle-adf

Trying to update a page through Ajax. Click a button and print out a counter on the page.

The following code works when deployed with JSF 2.0 mojarra on a Tomcat 7. It does not work when deployed from JDeveloper 11g to the built in Weblogic server. The count variable does get incremented, but the page is reloaded each time when using ADF.

Backing Bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.*;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

@ManagedBean(name="countBean")   
@SessionScoped
public class CountBean {
    Integer count=1;
    public void incrementCount(ActionEvent event) {
        ++count;
    }
    public Integer getCount() { return count;}
    public void setCount(Integer count) {   this.count = count; }           
}
```

JSF-page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head><title>Ajax commandButton test</title></h:head>
<h:body>
<h3>Ajax count</h3>
<h:form>
<h:commandButton id="cb" value="Increment count" 
   actionListener="#{countBean.incrementCount}">
    <f:ajax event="click" execute="cb" render="ot" />
</h:commandButton>
<br/><br/>
Counter = <h:outputText id="ot" value="#{countBean.count}"/>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Open page in browser, rightclick and *View Source*. Do you see differences in the HTML source from the both servers? I *guess* that `jsf.js` is missing/broken somehow. Firebug/Chrome should tell you more about JS errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself:

```
<af:commandButton text="increment count" id="cb1" actionListener="#{countBean.incrementCount}" partialSubmit="true"/>

Counter = <af:outputText id="ot" value="#{countBean.count}" partialTriggers="cb1"/>
```